# What does test_func and view_func do in Python / Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to break-down the following code in Django to figure out what it's doing and edit it if necessary, but I can't quite figure out what a few of these functions are doing or where they're coming from.

Are test_func and view_func Django specific or are these built-in python functions?

**Conclusion:**
I'm not sure how/why I overlooked the fact that these were simply being defined as arguments to the functions.  I need to start paying better attention to details.

Here's the Django function I'm trying to break down / figure out:

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            print test_func
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(login_url or
                                                        settings.LOGIN_URL)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(path, login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`view_func` is a [Django view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/). `test_func` is a function "that checks that the user passes the given test".

So, you write a function that asks for something from the user, and returns `True` if they pass. Then you pass that function to `user_passes_test` and it creates a decorator you can use to first test a user before they get to see your view, like so:

```
@user_passes_test
def test_intelligence(user):
    if is_intelligent:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@test_intelligence
def my_view(request):
    #this is the view you only want intelligent people to see
    pass
```

Decorators are mentioned under [Function Definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) in the docs. `wraps` is a decorator that preserves the signature of the function being wrapped (name, args, etc) through the decoration process. It's located [in functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: my comment from another answer: wow i don't know why i overthought that so much.. i was thinking they were built in python functions for some reason.. basically I'm just trying to figure out how they're being used in this particular case. I'm assuming decorator is being called automatically somehow because there is no direct call to it in when user_passes_test() is being called on it.

Comment: whoops.. i just noticed "return decorator"  thought it was inside of the function for some reason.  I need to pay better attention to details

Comment: relax.. I'm reading through each one again to see which of the two better answered the question

Answer (score 2):

`test_func` and `view_func` are functions passed in as arguments -- that is, the names are just arbitrary variables names. [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) is a [decorator](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) which is applied to a view (which becomes the variable `view_func`) -- it's passed a function as argument (`test_func`) which takes a `User` and returns `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

[Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) that inherit from [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) define a `test_func` method that performs the same function as the decorator parameter described in the existing answers [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989937/5320906), [2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989925/5320906), that is it determines whether the user may view the page.

```py
class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.some_atttribute == acceptable_Value
```